# Find invalid data validation cells

Tags: vba, list, excel, validation

### Description:

I have created a custom dropdown data validation list where I can choose among several values. These values on the dropdown list changes as I need (are defined in a worksheet column X).

### Problem:

My problem occurs when I choose one of those values, let say Y, from the dropdown list and then I update the data validation by removing the last inserted value (deleted the Y value from column X). By doing this the value Y present in the worksheet is no longer valid so I would like to know if there is a way to obtain a list (array or string) of cells with the invalid data.

### What I have done/thought so far:

I have searched in several sites and read similar questions but I cannot find anything usefull. I thought about looping all the cells and check if the value is valid but since I have a huge amount of data I think that it is not the best approach.

Since Excel already mark these invalid data with a red circle maybe it could be possible to get the address of those marked cells?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How huge is your dataset? If this is a function that will only be run once in awhile you'd need an absolutely massive to make something that not worth the time.

Comment: You can use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)` to get at all the cells that contain validation and then loop through them looking for ones where the cells `Validation.Value` property is false.  Refer Microsoft's article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213773.  I found that article by reading the second result from a google search of `excel vba find invalid data`. (I ignored the first result as it was this question.)

Comment: @Taelsin The data to be checked would be around tens of thousands and the valid values around tens. That's why I was wondering if there was another option to do this (which seems to exist as written in the other comments). But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @pnuts I did not post any code because I was trying to not bias a solution since I was looking for something that would avoid my dummy solution of looping across all the values and check them one by one. I need the addresses in order to go directly to those incorrect cells one by one and force the user edit them instead of just marking a red circle or throw a warning.

Comment: @YowE3K Indeed I was looking for something like that! Just to let you know I searched in Google (before posting the question) using keywords like `excel vba data validation incorrect wrong list dropdown` in several combinations but none of them returned the link you provided. And even searching with your keywords I just found the link you provided in the middle of my 2nd page, but thank you :)

Comment: Since I got the answer I needed to this question but nobody posted it as an answer what should I do? Edit my question and post the solution? Post a kind of template with the usefull code as an answer? Close the question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pnuts (3rd comment) I can edit my question and add the dummy code I have done. I did not do it in the moment I posted the question because I thought it would lead to a solution that I was trying to avoid since the amount of data to be compared is huge. (4th comment) I will post an answer then, thank you :)

Comment: @pnuts - Without code in the original question to give clues to the "personalisation" needed for the OP's situation, the only code I could post as a possible solution would probably end up being a direct plagiarisation of Microsoft's sample, so I am not offended by a self-answer in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to obtain the invalid cells in a worksheet is using `Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)`.

By using some information present in [Microsoft KB213773 (Q213773) - "How to create data validation circles for printing in Excel"](http://web.archive.org/web/20150404002955/http://support.microsoft.com:80/en-us/kb/213773) a similar `Sub` can be used to loop all invalid cells and then change their values (or mark them to future edit).

```
Sub CorrectInvalidValues()

    Dim data_range As Range
    Dim invalid_cell As Range
    Dim count As Integer: count = 0
    Dim nr_invalid As Integer: nr_invalid = 0
    Dim new_value As String

    'If an error occurs run the error handler and end the procedure
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    Set data_range = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Loop through each cell that has data validation and gets the number of invalid cells
    For Each invalid_cell In data_range
        If Not invalid_cell.Validation.Value Then
            nr_invalid = nr_invalid + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' Editing each value
    For Each invalid_cell In data_range
        If Not invalid_cell.Validation.Value Then
            count = count + 1
            Application.Goto reference:=invalid_cell, Scroll:=True
            new_value = Application.InputBox("Please insert a correct value.", "Invalid Data " & count & "/" & nr_invalid)

            If Not (new_value = "False") Then
                invalid_cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                invalid_cell.Value = new_value
            Else
                invalid_cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                invalid_cell.Value = "<PLEASE EDIT>"
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Exit Sub

errhandler:
    MsgBox "There are no cells with data validation on this sheet."

End Sub
```

Comment: I can not see how to use your sugestion, since the `nr_invalid` is the total number of invalid cells and I use that variable in order to get the "percentage" of completed work (displayed in the title of the `InputBox`). If I merge both `If`s it will be updating the `Application.InputBox` with a total number of invalid cells that is not final. Or is another thing you are sugesting? (And thanks for the feedback!)

Comment: My apologies - I didn't see `nr_invalid` being used because I didn't scroll far enough to the right.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, I guess you could speed things up by not using `nr_invalid` but instead determine a percentage by taking how far through the second loop you are (valid or invalid) and dividing that by `data_range.Cells.Count`.  Depends on whether you are just trying to show an exact count of how much work they have to do, or a proportion of how far through they are.

Comment: I may not explained nicely in my last comment when I said "percentage" but it should be something like `Error 1 of 23` and not `Cell 34 of 300`. Since it is just a counter (and hopefully there will not be more than hundreds of errors at a time in my case) it should perform fast enough (at least for my case it is doing well). Or you are saying something else? (if you don't mind you could sugest na edit to I understand if what you are saying is what I am understanding)

Comment: No, I'm definitely not suggesting anything more than what you think I am.  (It's rare for people to understand what I am talking about, but you are one of the few who succeeded!)  Half-way through posting my last comment I noticed that the "/" in your code wasn't calculating an actual percentage but rather an "x of y" type message, but I was just thinking that a "x% finished" message **may** be nearly as useful.  If your time isn't impacted by showing the exact progress, stick with what you have. :-)